# Does "Build active architecture only" do anything if I have no iOS device connected to my Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've realised all the libraries I use have "Build active architecture only" set to true for debug and release. When I look up "Build active architecture only" it seems to be about detecting what device you have connected for testing, and building for that device's architecture.

So if I built all my libraries without any iOS device attached, will this setting have had any effect? Rebuilding everything is a bit of a slow process, and many of my libraries are CMake-generated, which means extra complications.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but you can find out pretty easily: build your app without any device connected to the computer and see what Xcode generates. There are a couple of ways to check. The easiest is probably to go to the build results tab (⌘-8), click the latest Build and search for the name of one of your source files. If it only built for a single architecture, then you should only see one Compile entry for the file. If it built for all architectures, you'll see an entry for every architecture. For what it's worth, I just tried it with Xcode 5.0.2 and it built for all architectures.

Another way to check, by the way, is by finding the built product (probably in DerivedData) and doing:

> lipo -info ProjectX.app/ProjectX

This will list every architecture that was included when building. For my test, it printed:

> Architectures in the fat file: ProjectX are: armv7 armv7s arm64

After plugging in my iPhone 5 and rebuilding:

> Non-fat file: ProjectX.app/ProjectX is architecture: armv7s

Comment: By the way, I have no idea how that setting will be propagated to your CMake projects. It is entirely possible CMake will override the setting and always build for all architectures regardless. If that is the case, the CMake projects can probably be tweaked to do otherwise. It's been a long while since I've used CMake, though, so unfortunately I can't really say more than that.

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for taking the time to test.